# Finding a sub-string with indices from both ends

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to extract a sub string with an starting index and index from the last

for example

```
val = "SUBSTRING"
|||||||||||||||||
12345678901234567
```

I need the string from  start index = 8 and end index  = -2  (length of sub string is variable of course)

I know its a very basic question but is there any direct way to do it using single command?

Comment: are you programming in bash? csh? c? c++? Linux is not a programming language...

Comment: I am programming in bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter substring expansion:

```
string='val = "SUBSTRING"'
echo "${string:7:-1}"
```

The starting position is 7, as the numbering starts from 0.

> If length evaluates to a number less than zero, [ ... ] it is interpreted as an offset from the end of the value of parameter rather than a number of characters, and the expansion is the characters between the two offsets.

Comment: isn't it position and length?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: No, only the offset needs the space, to avoid confusion with the `${var:-default}` construct.

Answer (score 0):

just try to use `cut -c startIndx-stopIndx`

For ex:

```
   1) start=5;stop=9; echo "the rain in spain" | cut -c $start-$(($stop-1))
```

output : **rain**

```
   2) start=5;stop=9; echo "theRainInSpain" | cut -c $start-$(($stop-1))
```

output : **ainI**

Comment: read the question please. there are 100s of answers doing what you have done.

Comment: My Stop index is from last